# How to get div with selected text?

Tags: javascript, html, select, text

I have `div` with `contenteditable="true"`. How to get `div` by select text? For example

```
<div class="md-editor" contenteditable="true"><div class="imustgetthidivbyselecttext">help</div>
```

When I select text, how to get class that is in `div` text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If contenteditable="true" div is parent div then you can use below code

```
<div class="md-editor" contenteditable="true"><div class="imustgetthidivbyselecttext" onclick='call(this);'>help</div></div>

function call(id) {
        alert(id.className); // For current div
        alert(id.parentElement.className); // For parent div where contenteditable="true"
    }
```

Comment: Let me know if you are looking for something else

Answer (score 0):

Update:  This works in Chrome.  Might be slightly different in older IE versions:

```
window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer.parentElement;
```

Fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/xs36c3a5/

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getSelectedText() {
    var text = '';
    
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    }
    else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    
    return text;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" style="border: solid 1px black; width: 300px;">hello world</div>
<input type="button" onclick="alert(getSelectedText())" value="Get selected text" />
```